# Columns return as 0, 0, 0

Tags: javascript, bonita

I am using **Bonita BPM**.

I have used some **javascript** expressions and Strings for variable assignments. Now i want to return the input feilds following the documentation where i can use `formInput.travelRequestInput.numberOfNights` to capture form inputs and then save from the UI designer to the **H2 Database**.

in this case i did something like this for javascript to perform calculations :

```
var resultCalculate = Number($data.perdiemInput) * Number($data.noOfNightsInput);
return resultCalculate;
```

How ever this is working beautifully well. Now i want to use the variables (3) of them which are **javascript** expressions and send their data to the **H2 database**. along with other information, other information saves just the one which has to deal with the doubles and co.

i have other data in their respective columns , fine and good except the one for the javascript expressions How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of the data flow in Bonita from the web forms displayed in the user web browser to the business database managed by Bonita (relying on h2 usually in test environment):

1. Widgets are bind to a JavaScript object using the "value" property of the widget: modification of the widget value update the JavaScript object and modification of the JavaScript object update the displayed value.
2. The form submit button (that will start a new process instance or execute a task) will send the data of a single form variable (configured using the "Data to sent on click" property). The value of this single form variable can be set using a JavaScript expression that aggregate multiple forms variables.
3. When the user click on the button data are sent as JSON in an HTTP request from the user web browser to Bonita Engine.
4. Bonita Engine will parse the JSON information and verify that they actually match the contract defined to start the process or execute the task.
5. If contract match the value of JSON is used to initialize the contract variable.
6. Contract can then be used in process business variable (default value) or in operations on task to create (insert) or update data store in the BDM database.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Actually, to be more accurate, the issue is I think in the incoherence between the structure of the data sent by the submit button in the form and the expect data by the contract. The answer should provide enough guidance to locate more precisely the issue (especially if using the web browser developer tools) by better understanding the concept lying behind the form submission processing.